# Why use SNS to trigger a lambda function, and not API gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-sns

I've seen a lot of people using SNS to trigger their lambda function rather than using the API gateway to do it. Any specific reasons to do this?

Personally i think allowing the API gateway to do this is a lot more flexible than using SNS. Any good elaboration as to why do this ? Would i get any performance or cost improvements if i use SNS to trigger the function?

Comment: It may be the case that you misunderstand the applications involved.  You can *trigger* a Lambda function in response to an event, from SNS, SQS, DynamoDB, Kinesis, S3, and other sources.  You can *invoke* a Lambda function through API Gateway, from an Application Load Balancer, from CloudFront (Lambda@Edge, Node.JS functions only), or directly using the Lambda service API.  In most cases, the most (or only) appropriate mechanism is readily apparent.  Check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/invoking-lambda-function.html and see if you can expand/clarify the nature of this question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TLDR**: The choice boils down to *request-response* vs. *publish-subscribe* models.

*Request-Response*:

- If **you need to know what the Lambda returns**, you have to invoke the Lambda *synchronously* and wait for the result.
- This can be done through API Gateway (from client applications) or by directly invoking the Lambda *synchronously* (from other Lambdas).
- Examples are typical HTTP requests, REST APIs, etc.

*Publish-Subscribe*:

- If **you don't care what the return value is**, you can invoke the Lambda ***async***hronously and move on **without** waiting for the result.
- When something is published to an SNS topic, a Lambda that subscribes to that topic will then get triggered.
- The publisher doesn't care what the subscribers will do.
- Examples are usually background task triggers like sending emails, sending SMS, or starting long-running tasks like video transcoding, image processing, web scraping, etc.